# Aurelia.js Framework aurelia-table pagination

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am using : https://tochoromero.github.io/aurelia-table/

I have just a small issue and I would like ask your help.

```
  <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="data.bind: 
    filters.bind: filters;
    current-page.bind: currentPage; 
    page-size.bind: pageSize; 
    total-items.bind: totalItems;">
  </table>

  <label>${currentPage} - ${pageSize} of  ${totalItems}</label>
```

I have 5 pages and I would show like: 1 of 5 pages os 33 items, I tried use: `pagination-size:` but did not work for me, can someone help me with this?  thank you.

Comment: What happens if you switch from using `bind` to using `two-way` on the bindings?

Comment: what two-way means there? I could not find this.

Comment: You can force a binding to be two way by using `two-way` on the binding. @Jesse uses this in the accepted answer: `current-page.two-way: currentPage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your total amount of items, and you know how many are gonna be on each page, it's a matter of simple math.

```
// Compute the amount of pages.
var amountOfPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- two-way binding as suggested in the comments to update the variables in the viewmodel -->
<table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="data.bind: data;
  filters.bind: filters;
  current-page.two-way: currentPage; 
  page-size.bind: pageSize; 
  total-items.two-way: totalItems;">
</table>
<label>Page: ${currentPage} of ${amountOfPages} (${totalItems} items)</label>
```

If you data is dynamic and can update, you can turn the variable into a `get`-function:

```
@computedFrom('totalItems', 'pageSize')
public get amountOfPages() {
  return Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
}
```

Comment: very helpfull, thank you, but I dont know why the totalPages it is not loading in my html, the other ones it is but this one no.

Comment: Ah, it turns out you don't need to bind that variable

Comment: in my view (js) I was doing this: this.pageSize = 10;  this.currentPage = 1; so I included: totalPages = 1, but still not showing anything :(

Comment: I think the `totalPages` only works inside an `aut-pagination` element. Does the first option (computing it manually) work for you?